# Appropriate Api was not requested. Disconnect from Google Fit

Tags: android, google-fit

I am getting a null pinter exception while am disconnecting from google fit

```
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Appropriate Api was not requested.
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx.zzb(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzli.zza(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf.zza(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf.zzb(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzli.zzb(Unknown Source)
E/Androi
```

This is my code to disconnecting

```
public void disableGoogleFit(GoogleApiClient mClient) {
    if (!mClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Google Fit wasn't connected");
        return;
    }
    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = Fitness.ConfigApi.disableFit(mClient);

    pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit disabled");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Fit wasn't disabled " + status);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `ConfigApi` when you building `GoogleApiClient`Like below.

```
new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.SESSIONS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
```

Thats it .